# Inserting an image file into mysql database not working

Tags: mysql

The following is the command that I am trying

```
 insert into test values(1,LOAD_FILE('/home/smith/Desktop/logo.1.png'));
```

The error is saying that the `img` column should not be null.  As I am giving `img` `LOAD_FILE` why it is saying that?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. 
>           To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. 
>           The file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. 
>       If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

**If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.**

1. File existance
2. Absolute path
3. Permissions
4. Size

Comment: i have checked all the above conditions all are satisfied and i have also granted FILE privilige for that user.Still i am getting the same problem.

Comment: is the type of field BLOB?

Answer (score 0):

Without insert File, store file name in database

```
$name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]
$path = "./upload"
$ext = pathinfo($path ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_name = $name.'.'.$ext;
```

So insert should be

```
INSERT INTO test (id, filename) VALUES (1, '$file_name');
```

Some useful links

1. [PHP 5 File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) //file upload, Exist check, size, validation

Answer (score -1):

I think you should give  ownership of file to mysql user try the command below

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /home/smith/Desktop/logo.1.png
```